# Problem with inequality constraint

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm using [`NMinimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMinimize.html) to solve the following objective function.

```
S1 = 0.874334;

S2 = 0.125666;

Wd11[R_] := Exp[-((R - 6.491541)/34.9807)^1.506582];

V11[R_] := Wd11[R]*S1;

Wd12[Q_, R_] := Exp[-(((R + ((1 - 0.5)*Q)) - 14.19834)/53.64985)^1.701898];

V12[Q_, R_] := Wd12[Q, R]*S1;

Wd21[Q_, R_] := Exp[-(((R + 0.5*Q) - 13.3108)/45.07249)^1.690368];

V21[Q_, R_] := Wd21[Q, R]*S2;

Wd22[R_] := Exp[-((R - 10.4539)/39.29455)^1.617706];

V22[R_] := Wd22[R]*S2;

a := V11[R] + V12[R, Q] + V21[R, Q] + V22[R];

f[Q_] := If[1 <= Q <= 1000, 75, 
   If[1000 < Q <= 3000, 74, 
    If[3000 < Q <= 7000, 73, 
     If[7000 < Q <= 15000, 71.5, 
      If[15000 < Q <= 26000, 70.5, If[Q > 26000, 69, 0]]]]]];

T[Q_] := 850*1.6*(IntegerPart[(Q*22*0.5)/45000]) + (850*1.6*0.7^
     Log[2, 45000/(FractionalPart[(Q*0.5*22)/45000]*45000)]);
```

The objective function is:

```
OB[Q_, R_] := ((3650*f[Q]) + (3650/Q*(T[Q] + T[Q])) + (3650/
       Q (50 + 2*50)) + (0.25*
       f[Q]*(Q/2 - (0.5*10*(6 - 4)) + (R - (4*10)))) + (0.18*
       f[Q]*(3*10)))*15;
```

So,

```
NMinimize[{OB[Q, R], Q >= 1, R >= 1, a <= 0.02}, {Q, R}]
```

but it results in the following errors:

> LessEqual::nord: Invalid comparison with 1.93457 +0.143499 I
>   attempted. >>
>
> NMinimize::bcons: The following constraints are not valid:
>   {Q>=1,R>=1,0.874334 E^(-0.00113881
>   (-14.1983+Q+Times[<<2>>])^1.7019)+0.125666 E^(-0.00160059
>   (-13.3108+Q+Times[<<2>>])^1.69037)+0.125666 E^(-0.00263535
>   (-10.4539+R)^1.61771)+0.874334 E^(-0.00472167
>   (-6.49154+R)^1.50658)<=0.02}. Constraints should be equalities,
>   inequalities, or domain specifications involving the variables. >>

I've checked this error on many pages and tried different solutions, but it still doesn't work. The problem actually arises from the third constraint (`a <= 0.02`). When I place `a == 0.02`, it gives an output, but I'm not sure if this output is correct. Anyway, why shouldn't it give me the output when `a <= 0.02`?

Thank you

Comment: `a` can be complex in your code, do you want it to be real-valued?

Answer (score 2):

The error you get is the same error you get when you evaluate `3 < 4 + 2I` - you are asking if a complex number is less than a real-valued one.

Take the answer you get when you put in the equality, and then feed that back into `a`

```
NMinimize[{OB[Q, R], Q >= 1, R >= 1, a == 0.02}, {Q, R}]
(* {4.31243*10^6, {Q -> 478.281, R -> 94.4141}} *)

a /. %[[2]]
(* 0.967752 + 1.21616*10^-12 I *)
```

and you see it has a small imaginary part.  If you demand that `a` be real, you get a convergence error

```
NMinimize[{OB[Q, R], Q >= 1, R >= 1, Re[a] <= 0.02, 
  Im[a] == 0}, {Q, R}]
```

> During evaluation of In[--]:= NMinimize::incst: NMinimize was unable
>   to generate any initial points satisfying the inequality constraints
>   {-0.02+Re[0.874334 E^(-0.00113881 Power[<<2>>])+0.125666
>   E^(-0.00160059 Power[<<2>>])+0.125666 E^(-0.00263535
>   Power[<<2>>])+0.874334 E^(-0.00472167 Power[<<2>>])]<=0}. The initial
>   region specified may not contain any feasible points. Changing the
>   initial region or specifying explicit initial points may provide a
>   better solution. >>

```
(* {4.31243*10^6, {Q -> 478.132, R -> 94.4141}} *)
```

which you can solve by giving an initial guess.

```
NMinimize[{OB[Q, R], Q >= 1, R >= 1, Re[a] <= 0.02, 
  Im[a] == 0}, {{Q, 478, 480}, {R, 90, 100}}]
(* {4.31243*10^6, {Q -> 478.287, R -> 94.4141}} *)
```

Notice this value is slightly higher than the previous answer, so there is a price to pay by demanding `a` be real.

Edit:
Okay, so you wanna be **sure** that this is the minimum value - well, minimum on what interval?  Let's just take `Q` and `R` from 1 to 1000 and find the minimum manually.

```
data1 = Flatten[Table[{q, r, OB[q, r], a /. {Q -> q, R -> r}}, {q, 1, 1000, 
    1}, {r, 1, 1000, 1}],1];
```

Select the values according to your inequality

```
data2 = Select[data1, (Re[#[[4]]] <= 0.02 &)];
```

and pick the minimum,

```
Sort[data2, #2[[3]] > #1[[3]] &][[1]]
(* {478, 95, 4.3126*10^6, 0.0192163} *)
```

which makes me trust the values found above via `NMinimize`

Comment: Thank you Jason. But is this result reliable? I mean, is that correct and can I use it for my analysis?

Comment: You tell me - I have no idea what these equations mean really.  Is it necessary that `a` be real?

Comment: Yes, it should be. However, if the difference is that small, it doesn't matter. Moreover, you determined the initial guess by getting the results when a == 0.02. I selected an interval {Q, 100, 1000}, {R, 40, 1000} and got the same results as yours (when {Q, 478, 480}, {R, 90, 100}). But when {Q, 1, 10000}, {R, 40, 10000}, I got another result. Then, I think I can't choose any interval, right?

Comment: I got it now. Thank you.